# CSS @media keeps original css

Tags: php, html, css

I am working on a responsive website,
Here i have 4 divs inside a main div.

On desktop fullscreen you will see the 4 divs next to eachother

[image]

But once the screen goes below 1025px it should

Be 2 divs next to eachother and 2 divs below that ( 2x2 )

but once it goes below 1025px it keeps the main styling aswell[image] and the blocks are still 4 wide

```css
.grid-wide-4-block-main {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.grid-wide-4-block {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  height: 1000px;
  max-width: auto;
  width: auto;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 1620px;
}

.grid-wide-logo {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.grid-wide-4-blocks {
  min-width: 20%;
  margin-left: 3%;
  margin-right: 3%;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0.2rem 0.4rem rgb(0 0 0 / 10%), 0 0.67rem 2rem rgb(0 0 0 / 10%);
}

.grid-wide-4-block-inside {
  margin: 5px;
}

.grid-wide-4-title {
  color: orange;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1025px) {
  .grid-wide-4-block {
    max-width: 1025px;
    height: 1000px;
  }
  .grid-wide-4-blocks {
    min-width: 45%;
    height: 40%;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 0.2rem 0.4rem rgb(0 0 0 / 10%), 0 0.67rem 2rem rgba(171, 77, 40, 0.1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-wide-4-block-main">
  <div class="grid-wide-4-block">
    <?php echo $background; ?>

    <div class="grid-wide-4-block-1 grid-wide-4-blocks">
      <div class="grid-wide-4-block-inside">
        <?php if ($grid_wide_4_imageObj) : ?>
        <img class="grid-wide-4-image-1 grid-wide-logo" src="<?php echo $grid_wide_4_image_url; ?>" />
        <?php endif; ?>
        <h3 class="grid-wide-4-title">
          <?php echo $grid_wide_4_title; ?>
        </h3>
        <p class="grid-wide-4-summary-1">
          <?php echo $grid_wide_4_summary; ?>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-wide-4-block-2 grid-wide-4-blocks">
      <div class="grid-wide-4-block-inside">
        <?php if ($grid_wide_4_imageObj2) : ?>
        <img class="grid-wide-4-image-2 grid-wide-logo" src="<?php echo $grid_wide_4_image_url2; ?>" />
        <?php endif; ?>
        <h3 class="grid-wide-4-title">
          <?php echo $grid_wide_4_title2; ?>
        </h3>
        <p class="grid-wide-4-summary-2">
          <?php echo $grid_wide_4_summary2; ?>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-wide-4-block-3 grid-wide-4-blocks">
      <div class="grid-wide-4-block-inside">
        <?php if ($grid_wide_4_imageObj3) : ?>
        <img class="grid-wide-4-image-3 grid-wide-logo" src="<?php echo $grid_wide_4_image_url3; ?>" />
        <?php endif; ?>
        <h3 class="grid-wide-4-title">
          <?php echo $grid_wide_4_title3; ?>
        </h3>
        <p class="grid-wide-4-summary-3">
          <?php echo $grid_wide_4_summary3; ?>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-wide-4-block-4 grid-wide-4-blocks">
      <div class="grid-wide-4-block-inside">
        <?php if ($grid_wide_4_imageObj4) : ?>
        <img class="grid-wide-4-image-4 grid-wide-logo" src="<?php echo $grid_wide_4_image_url4; ?>" />
        <?php endif; ?>
        <h3 class="grid-wide-4-title">
          <?php echo $grid_wide_4_title4; ?>
        </h3>
        <p class="grid-wide-4-summary-4">
          <?php echo $grid_wide_4_summary4; ?>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Appears to be working fine here - https://jsfiddle.net/fhomL4su/

Comment: Does your document have a proper viewport meta tag? That is the basis for responsive layouts working properly. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag

Answer (score 0):

```
 .grid-wide-4-block {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        max-width: 1025px;
        height: 1000px;
      }

      .grid-wide-4-blocks {
       max-width: 45%;
       height: 400px;
       background-color: white;
       box-shadow: 0 0.2rem 0.4rem rgb(0 0 0 / 10%), 0 0.67rem 2rem rgba(171, 77, 40, 0.1);
    }
```

this should work